# How delete records from table A and B, if B does not contain specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to compose SQL query for deleting data from two tables - `A`, `B`. They are connected with a key and only I need to check, if in `B` is specific value `reservation` in one column.

Long story short, I have table with `rooms` and `beds` and I need to check, if there is any reservation in `room`. If not, I need to delete `room` itself and all of its `beds`.

I've tried two queries, but none of them gives me expected results. Table `B` is relatively large, so I'm trying to make it as fastest as possible, in one query.

```
-- gives me always 0 records
DELETE
  a, b
FROM
  rooms a, beds b
WHERE
  a.id = b.id_room AND
NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM beds WHERE id_room = '45' AND state != 'reservation')


-- deletes all records, but rows where state = 'reservation'
DELETE
  a, b
FROM 
  rooms a, beds b
WHERE
  a.id = b.id_room AND id_room = '45' AND state != 'reservation'
```

**Example dataset:**

```
-- rooms
-------------
| id | Name |
-------------
| 1  | 601  |
| 2  | 602  |
| 3  | 603  |

-- beds
-----------------------------|
| id | id_room | state       |
-----------------------------|
| 1  | 1       | free        |
| 2  | 1       | free        |
| 3  | 1       | reservation |
| 4  | 2       | free        |
| 5  | 2       | free        |
| 6  | 3       | reservation |
```

**Expected results:**

Rooms `1` and `3` have value `reservation` in column `state` in table `beds`, so it can not be deleted. Room `2` has no reservation, so it can be deleted and it should be deleted including all its beds - so the query should delete record `2` from table `rooms` and records `4` and `5` from table `beds`.

I always want to delete only one room (with its beds), so I need to include condition about room `ID` to calculate with.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected result as tabular text

Comment: @scaisEdge , Gordon Linoff - I added example dataset and described expected result, I hope it help to clarify my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
select id_room
from (
  select id_room, state from beds
  union
  select ?, ''
) t 
where id_room = ?
group by id_room
having sum(state = 'reservation') = 0
```

returns the `id` of the room that should be deleted, either because there is no `'reservation'` for any of its beds or it has no beds.
Replace both `?` with the id of the room that you search for.

Join it to the tables in the `DELETE` statement:

```
delete r, b
from rooms r 
inner join (
  select id_room
  from (
    select id_room, state from beds
    union
    select ?, ''
  ) t 
  where id_room = ?
  group by id_room
  having sum(state = 'reservation') = 0
) t on t.id_room = r.id
left join beds b
on b.id_room = t.id_room
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6050b6b3d2f786d0c6bca0e657cc0f23).

Comment: Perfect, I added condition `WHERE id_room = {ID_ROOM}` and that's exactly what I need. Thank you very much, you saved my day.

Comment: Now, I found small issue. If there is no record in `beds` table, so if room have no beds yet, this query does not delete it. Is here any chance to edit conditions to delete room in case like this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a left join between the table and check for not matching values

```
    DELETE  beds, rooms
    FROM  rooms a
    LEFT  JOIN beds b ON a.id = b.id_room 
        AND b.state = 'reservation'
    WHERE b.id_room is null
```

and based on  your code sample

```
SELECT a.id, b.id 
FROM  rooms a 
LEFT  JOIN beds b ON a.id = b.id_room 
AND b.state = 'reservation' and 
    b.id_room = 45 WHERE b.id_room is null

    DELETE romms, beds
    FROM  rooms a
    LEFT  JOIN beds b ON a.id = b.id_room 
        AND b.state = 'reservation'
    WHERE b.id_room is null
    AND  a.id = 45
```

Comment: It seemingly works, but the query deletes records from table `A` only, table `B` is untouched. I also added condition about the `ID` of the room, but it did not affect the result.

Comment: using  the syntax delete ....  from the tables between delete andfrom should be delete  .. so try check better anyway ..  sligthly change using expiiclit table name id_room..  .. eventually try post the code you are really using ..

Comment: If I changed `DELETE` to `SELECT` to see what records are selected, I've got list of all rooms (in `a.id`) and in `b.id` is `NULL` in all records. I am trying your query, only I added condition about `id_room`, becase I always need to check only room with specific ID, not all of them. `SELECT a.id, b.id FROM  rooms a LEFT  JOIN beds b ON a.id = b.id_room AND b.state = 'reservation' and b.id_room = 45 WHERE b.id_room is null`

Comment: This query sucessfully delete `room`, but not `beds`. I am not sure, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: are you sure you have not some store procedure somewhere ??   are you sure the join clause is correct  and coherent with the data used  for test   .. anyway answer  updated ..  changed  order for table name  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge the condition `WHERE b.id_room is null` returns only the unmatched rows. So only rows from rooms are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
DELETE r, b
    FROM rooms r JOIN
         beds b
         ON a.id = b.id_room LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT b2.id_room
          FROM beds b2
          WHERE b2.state = 'reservation'
         ) b2
         ON b2.id_room = b.id_room
    WHERE b2.id_room IS NULL;
```

Comment: It gives me this error `Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause`.

Comment: @sylar32 . . . Duh!  I fixed the answer to use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: Now it works, but this query deletes all rooms and all beds, no matter `reservation` is contained or not. I added condition `AND b2.id_room = 45` in the subquery, because I always need to check only one room, not all of them. I am not sure, if I correctly explained what I need to delete. I added example dataset and expected result above to clarify my issue.

Comment: @Sylar32 . . . I didn't realize the "45" was specific to the question.  I figured you really wanted to delete all rooms that met the criteria.  You could just add that condition to the outer query.